# Case Validation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need  case  validation in Jquery.  means  if  my  textbox  having  "kapil kumar". so   user  can  change  only  case of word  not  any character  value.  I  mean  user  can  change  only case  of  word  for  ex.  "KAPIL kumar" they  can  use  upper  case  lower  case  but  they  can't  change  value  of  word
.I  am  using  MVC3.

Comment: Are you doing the validation only on the client side? If so, it does not depend on MVC 3. Also post some code that you have tried.. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @ryadavilli: I am new to Jquery. I have no idea about this logic.

Comment: Ok, but you still havent answered the part about where you want to do this validation. If it is purely on the client side, the code that Murali Prasanth posted below is good.

Comment: Ya its a client side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($.trim($("#textboxId").val().toLowerCase()) === "kapil kumar"){
   //do something
}
```